# Vue composable - how to use multiple instances of composable without sharing state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a composable file in my VueJS application:

```
// simple example of a composable that fetch some information from API and shows that information 
// in a table in two components at the sime time
export function useDatatable () {
  const table = ref({
    headers: [...],
    items: [],
    someValue: ''
  })

  async function getDocuments () {
    const { data } = await $axios.get('/documents')
    table.value.items = data
  }

  return {
    table,
    getDocuments
  }
}
```

Then I have multiple components that use this composable at the same time:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <document-table /> // composable is used here
    <document-billing-dialog /> // composable is used here too
  </div>
</template>
```

Then in both components (`document-table` and `document-billing-dialog`) I use this composable like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ table.someValue }}
  </div>
  <v-table :items="table.items" />
  <v-btn @click="getDocuments">
    Reload table
  </v-btn>
  // other components
</template>

<script>
  import { useDatatable } from '~/composables/useDatatable'
  // other imports

  export default defineComponent({
    setup () {
      const { table, getDocuments } = useDatatable()

      onMounted(() => { getDocuments() })

      return {
        table,
        getDocuments
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

However when 1 component calls the `getDocuments` function it gets called twice because its being used in two components at the same time.

Other example is that if I change the value of `table.value.someValue = 'something'` it changes in both components.

Is there any way to have multiple instances of a composable at the same time without sharing the state?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem on an online playground? This [stackblizt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-n6bry9?file=src/pages/Home.vue) shows that the state of variables on different composable are independent

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across the same problem. My solution is, to separate the composable function

```
// simple example of a composable that fetch some information
// from API and shows that information 
// in a table in two components at the sime time

let tables = reactive([])

export default function useDatatable(datatableName) {
  tables[datatableName] = datatable()
  return tables[datatableName]
}

function datatable {
  const table = ref({
    headers: [...],
    items: [],
    someValue: ''
  })

  async function getDocuments() {
    const {
      data
    } = await $axios.get('/documents')
    table.value.items = data
  }

  return {
    table,
    getDocuments
  }
}
```

Initiate the composable with a name

```
<script>
  import useDatatable from '~/composables/useDatatable'
  // other imports

  export default defineComponent({
    setup () {
      const { table, getDocuments } = useDatatable('table-1')
    ...
```